# Howto find and move a text line inside a file?

Tags: text-processing, perl, pam

I need to change a text line position inside a file; from one line position to another one, underneath a defined text.

For example, I have the following text block (on /etc/pam.d/system-auth file)

```
account  required   pam_unix.so
account  sufficient pam_localuser.so
account  required   pam_permit.so
account  required   pam_tally2.so
```

And I want to 'move' the last line to be on the 2nd line (underneath the one which contains pam_unix.so)

How can this by done using a Perl command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used this workaround to solve my problem...

```
/bin/grep "pam_tally2.so" /etc/pam.d/system-auth
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then

#looks for line existence (pam_tally2.so) and delete it (if present)

/usr/bin/perl -i -pe 'chomp,$_.="" if /account\s.*required\s.*pam_tally2.so/' /etc/pam.d/system-auth
/usr/bin/find  /etc/pam.d/system-auth.bkp | /usr/bin/xargs perl -pi -e 's/account\s*required\s*pam_tally2.so//'

#inserts the -deleted- line underneath pam_unix.so line, as desired. Creating a 'moving line' result.

/usr/bin/perl -i -pe 'chomp,$_.="\n" if /account\s.*required\s.*pam_unix.so/' /etc/pam.d/system-auth
/usr/bin/perl -i -pe 'chomp,$_.="\naccount     required      pam_tally2.so\n" if /account\s.*required\s.*pam_unix.so/' /etc/pam.d/system-auth
fi
```

Comment: That doesn't answer your question though.

Comment: Worked for me :D

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using the `Tie::File` module which ties a file's lines to an array variable:

```
perl -MTie::File -e '
        tie @lines,"Tie::File","your_file_here";
        $last_line = pop @lines;
        splice @lines,1,0,$last_line
'
```

The tied variable (`@lines`) becomes magical in the sense that whatever array operations you carry out on it affect the lines of the file it's tied to.

Comment: I've tried with the following: 

`perl -MTie::File -e '
        tie @account     required      pam_unix.so,"Tie::File","/etc/pam.d/system-auth.bkp";
        $account     required      pam_tally2.so = pop @account     required      pam_unix.so;
        splice @account     required      pam_unix.so,1,0,$account     required      pam_tally2.so
'`

And is not working - any clues?

Comment: @AndresHojman You can't use spaces or periods in your variable names. Try `@account_required_pam_unix` and `$account_required_pam_tally2` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
perl -e '@l=<>;($l[1],$l[$#l])=($l[$#l],$l[1]);print @l' < file 1<> file
```

(note that it overwrites the file in place without safety net).

With `ex`:

```
ex -sc 'd|1 put|wq' file
```

Comment: Tried with the following: `perl -e '@l=<>;($l[1],$l[$#l])=($l[$#l],$l[1]);print @l' < /etc/pam.d/system-auth 1<> /etc/pam.d/system-auth` - but is not making any changes :(

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question more precisely:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use List::MoreUtils qw(firstidx lastidx);  # you may have to install this from CPAN
use autodie;
use File::Copy;

my $f = '/etc/pam.d/system-auth';
open my $fh, '<', $f;
my @lines = <$fh>;
close $fh;

# find the first and last "auth" lines:
my $first = firstidx {/^account\b/} @lines;
my $last = lastidx {/^account\b/} @lines;

# remove
my $removed = splice @lines, $last, 1;
# insert
splice @lines, $first+1, 0, $removed;

# backup first
copy $f, "$f.bak";
open my $fh, '>', $f;
print $fh join('', @lines);
close $fh;
```

Comment: Of course, you're only solving this very specific case... Which is OP's example, not even the actual question. Adding in some generalization and explanation would make this a much better answer.